# How to increase font size in drop down list Excel

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, fonts

I know this question has been asked a few times. I want to increase the font size of a drop down list in `Excel`. I can get it going without any other `code` in the sheet but I've got a separate `sub` that hides/unhides specific `columns` based off values entered into `Column B`. I'm struggling to combine both functions into the same working `sheet`.

This is my attempt:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
                Case "X"
                    Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case "Y"
                    Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t

    End If

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you also [@PeterJames123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9394674/peterjames123)? Lol.

Comment: @BigBen, we are in the same class

Comment: You can call the other sub from the Change event handler

Comment: If you want to trigger both actions when the sheet changes, you can merge those 2 programs into the one `Worksheet_Change` program, i.e. add codes of "Increase dd list font size" into the end of `Worksheet_Change`. That way there is no need to add 2 functions of the same name to the same sheet (which is impossible)

Comment: @Mr.K. Could you please add this in the form of an answer?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I'm not following. Could you add some more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add the one line from your second sub to the first:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
                Case "X"
                    Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case "Y"
                    Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 '<<<
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```